# Can't select started VMWare Player 15.0.2 VM window

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I switched from VirtualBox to VMWare this week. My work computer has a 1080p monitor and my personal laptop has a 4K screen.

Everything is working fine on my work computer. `CTRL + ALT` to release KMB from VM window, double-click or `CTRL + G` to bind KBM to VM window.

It is my personal laptop with a 4k screen that is having some real issues and odd behavior.

I installed Ubuntu server to use as a Docker server with no GUI. On a 4K screen the window was incredibly small and only readable with my face like 5" from the screen. I Googled how to make it larger. Somewhere I read to do the following:

> Right-click the VMWare Player 15 shortcut > Properties > Compatibility > Change high DPI settings > Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: > System (Enhanced)

Restarted the VM and great! It is bigger and legible now!

Then it comes to trying to select the window... double-clicking (more like clicking dozens of times) seldom works. The mouse cursor just rapidly flashes like it is bouncing back and forth between the host and the VM. Sometimes I can type a letter or two and then it just stops. Sometimes I click the window then have have to `ALT + TAB` to another window and then back and then it works. But then I found out about `CTRL + G` which does works pretty consistently.

The real issue comes with the Windows 10 Insiders build VM I have. It is unusable and cannot be selected at all with, or without, `CTRL + G`. The mouse just flashes like it is switching between host and VM rapidly.

VMware tools is installed in both cases, but don't think it really doesn't anything for the Ubuntu Server since it is just CLI.

I've tried the following:

- Reverting back the DPI settings in properties, but it doesn't even show what selected earlier as being selected.
- Uninstalling VMware, cleaning up Program Files, AppData, etc. and then reinstalling. It seems like the DPI settings I changed are still being used, so I imagine it is being stored in the registry somewhere.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Windows 10 Pro host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to redo these steps:

> Right-click the VMWare Player 15 shortcut > Properties > Compatibility > Change high DPI settings > Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: > System (Enhanced)

But instead of `System (Enhanced)` I had to set it to application. Yeah, the Ubuntu Server window is really small again, but that isn't relevant to this question. That I'm just using it for a Docker server, so aside from the initial setup and starting it up, I don't really have a need to access it... yet.